# how to delete a workplace account on lumia 635?

Tags: settings

how to delete a workplace account on my phone?
tried pressing the delete option but whenever I do I receive an error stating that account could not be deleted.. help pls.

Comment: Is this account the one used for setting up the original phone, or an additional account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can usually delete a Workplace account. That would defeat the purpose in many situations. You will most likely have to contact whoever manages the account and get them to release it, then try deleting again.